# PAP and CHAP implementation using Java

Tags: encryption, appsec, authentication, java

I want to implement PAP and CHAP based authentication in my Java project how can I implement ? is there any API available in Java for using that protocol ?

Comment: Warning: PAP and CHAP have security problems.  If you're forced to use them by a legacy system you have to interoperate with, well, so be it -- but if you're building a new system and have the choice, I do not recommend their use.  It is better to use TLS.

Comment: What is TLS ? and please elaborate that how should I use that ?

Comment: Thanks for your interest, Bhavik!  Allow me to point out the "Search" bar in the upper-right on this site.  It is sometimes useful in answering questions like yours.  For instance, here's the second result for a search for "what is TLS?" on this site: [What's the difference between SSL, TLS, and HTTPS?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/5126/971).  And the first result for a search on "TLS" on Wikipedia also gives good information: [Transport Layer Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).

Comment: Thans for the details, now the question is how can I implement that thing in my java project ? Have you ever implemented this things ?

Comment: sorry, but this is the wrong place to ask that question: it is probably out of scope for this site.  A web search should turn up plenty of information about how to implement TLS.  Try searching on Stack Overflow, too (hint: try a search on `adding TLS` on Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for:

http://tinyradius.sourceforge.net/