# Why is TLS still commonly referred to as SSL?

Tags: tls, network, certificates, asp.net-core

I am developing in Visual Studio 2017 and I'm writing an asp.net core 2.0 web application. In the project properties there is a checkbox for Enable SSL. Any idea why this is called SSL instead of TLS?

Also, it seems folks refer to certificates as SSL Certificates instead of TLS certificates. Is that a industry practice?

Comment: Also see [What's the difference between SSL, TLS, and HTTPS?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/5127/151903). Though I myself prefer TLS, I find Thomas Pornin's argument [here](https://www.bearssl.org/naming.html) compelling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [best blog post](https://certsimple.com/blog/ssl-or-tls) that I have read about this states, in summary, that though TLS effectively replaced SSL nearly 19 years ago, TLS is still being referred to as SSL because SSL has been known to "convey meaning better" than TLS.

This is further supported by well-known companies still using the SSL naming convention in their products and services (e.g. OpenSSL, Mozilla SSL Config generator, SSL Labs SSL test).

Also, it seems this question may have already been resolved [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/92292/why-do-we-still-use-the-terms-ssl-and-https) and was closed due to it being primarily opinion based.